# JavaScript regular expression not giving me all the numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have this list item tag:

```
<li id="CurrentPage">page 1 of 24</li>
```

I am trying to get all of the numbers from it in JavaScript and so far I have tried these:

```
alert($("#CurrentPage").text().match(/[0-9]/));   (gave me 1)
alert($("#CurrentPage").text().match(/\d+/));     (gave me 1)
alert($("#CurrentPage").text().match(/[0-9]+$/)); (gave me 24)
```

I really thought the second attempt would get me all of them, please could someone explain please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work with global flag (`g`):

```
'page 1 of 24'.match(/\d+/g); // 1, 24
```

So in your case use:

```
 var numbers = $("#CurrentPage").text().match(/\d+/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
alert($("#CurrentPage").text().match(/\d+/ig))
```

Comment: You are matching digits, why `i`?

Comment: Good point, I typically ig in case I come back later and add to the regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($("#CurrentPage").text().match(/[0-9]+/g));
```

or better say

```
alert($("#CurrentPage").text().match(/\d+/g));
```

`g` is a global modifier